# Hibernate Search: Get all fields for faceting

Tags: hibernate-search

I want to place [facet requests](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-creating-faceting-request) to (some) indexed fields. In order to place a facet request, I need to know the name of the corresponding field.

Is there a way to programmatically get a list of field names annotated with `@Field`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question will depend on the version of Search you are using. If you are using a pre Search 5 release where it was possible to facet on any `@Field` (with the documented restrictions), then you can use the public metadata API to get all configured fields.

The entry point into the public metadata API is via `SearchFactory.getIndexedTypeDescriptor(Class<?> entityType)` which returns an `IndexedTypeDescriptor` for the specified entity type. You can then iterate the configured properties and for each properties get the list of configured fields.

As of Search 5, however, facet fields needs to be marked at configuration time using `@Facet(s)`. Only properties with this annotation can be faceted upon. Obviously the public metadata API should expose this as well. Unfortunately, this is not yet implemented - [HSEARCH-1853](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1853).

There is a workaround if you are happy to use some internal APIs which might change in the future. You would only need this until HSEARCH-1853 is implemented at which stage you could switch to this public (and supported) API.

Search also maintains something which is called an internal metadata API which it uses for all its inner workings. It is basically just a richer model of the public API which is more restrictive on what's exposed. Bottom lines, you want to get hold of the `org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.FacetMetadata`. To do so you need to get hold of the `DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity` which gives you access to the internal `org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.TypeMetadata`. Via this type metadata you can get access to `PropertyMetadata`, then `DocumentFieldMetadata` and finally `FacetMetadata`.

To get hold of the `DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity`, you could do something like this:

```
ExtendedSearchIntegrator integrator = ContextHelper.getSearchintegratorBySFI( sessionFactory );
IndexManager[] indexManagers = integrator.getIndexBinding( clazz ).getIndexManagers();
DirectoryBasedIndexManager indexManager = (DirectoryBasedIndexManager) indexManagers[0];
EntityIndexBinding indexBinding = indexManager.getIndexBinding(clazz);
DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity documentBuilder = indexBinding.getDocumentBuilder();
```

Note, the internal API might change at any stage. No guarantees regarding backwards compatibility and evolution of the API are given.